# A guy is taking pictures of my home and family, how do I decode his license plate?

Tags: text-recognition

I had no idea where to post this.

I'm trying to decode a license plate and take it to the police station. The police said that they'll try to decode it, with no promises. If they had a full license plate, there would be an investigation. There's a man, which is taking pictures of my house for two weeks now, mainly during night. We are all really scared so I thought that someone in the web will help me.

I have a set of 5 images with the best resolution I could possible come with my camera.

[Original link to images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csJjf.jpg)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried multiple approaches, mainly I read about `OCR` and the text recognition and tried online solutions, but couldn't came up with a good result because the image his car is in a really bad rotation and these systems say that the photo is too blurry. I know some photoshop so I've tried messing with the contrast, making a high-pass, filtering the image.

I came up with first two digits which are probably `WI` or `WL` but I'm really not sure.

I read that this kind of Q/A is not a place for solving problems like this directly, but I really don't know what to do here. I live in Poland. If you could help me, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Images do not show? Can you add one of them directly yo your post ?

Comment: The easiest solution might be to rent or borrow a camera with good low-light capability, like a Nikon D5, a tripod, and a long lens (300mm or more), and get a good shot of the license plate. Or, you or a friend might try to get close and take a quick shot with a cell phone without being noticed.

Comment: Somebody in exactly your situation have asked this question from me. Unfortunaty if a human can't read the plate, the plate recognition system or OCR or anything else wouldn't either.

Comment: Can't the police just go talk to the guy, if he's there every night?